# How to make child not inherit animation property

Tags: html, css

I'm experimenting with css animation property and making a spinner, but it turns out i can't make the childs (text) not rotate along with its direct parent,  i gave a thorough look to w3schools specs regarding to animation for details and searched for posts on this.. but so far got nothing.. Do you know if this can be done?? or after all...there needs to be a different approach in order to solve it??... Thank you in advance.

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#spinnerLayer{
 position: absolute;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.603); 
}

#spinner span{
  position: absolute;
  animation: reverse;
  font-size: .3em;
  letter-spacing: 0.010em;
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#spinner{
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left-color: cyan;
  border-right-color: cyan;
  animation: gira 2s infinite  forwards;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#spinner div{
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: inherit;
  border: 2.3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: cyan solid 2px;
  border-top: cyan solid 2px;
  animation: gira 7s infinite  forwards;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes gira{
  0%{
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="spinnerLayer">
     <div id="spinner">
      <span>99%</span>
        <div>

        </div>
     </div>
     <div></div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like you have copy pasted the code from somewhere but it's not complete. I can see there is a reverse animation declared in the code, but I don't see the animation code. Also, that's the solution, reverse the child animation and it should work as expected

Comment: @Mr.Alien, no, this is my own code... i applied reverse to animation but does nothing... specifically, any animation parameter that i add doesnt make a difference... it seems childs have animation property tweaked.

Comment: I even created a new keyframe which has rotate property set to 0 from start to end and assigned it to the child span, and all the same got the same result, sadly.....

Comment: @Mr.Alien, but if you set reverse parameter (not withstanding it also doesnt make a visual difference), span is gonna rotate the other way around, which is not my intention.

Answer (score 0):

I came with an answer to this issue, and sadly.. in the end *i got to wrap the #spinner with another div*, *move the span to it*, *and set both to position: absolute*, thereby since the wrapper adjusts its size automatically only according to its content text gets positioned to center avoiding this way being under animation property. So, this is a workaround.

**Resultant code:**

```css
 

   body{
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
        }
        #spinnerLayer{
         position: absolute;
         padding: 0;
         margin: 0;
         z-index: 2;
         width: 100vw;
         height: 100vh;
         background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.603); 
        }
        #spinnerLayer > div {
          position: absolute;
    
        }
        span{
          
          position: absolute;
          font-size: .3em;
          letter-spacing: 0.010em;
          color: white;
          left: 50%;
          top: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    
          
      
        }
        #spinner{
          padding: 2px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          border: 2px solid transparent;
          display: inline-block;
          border-left-color: cyan;
          border-right-color: cyan;
          animation: gira 2s infinite  forwards;
          animation-direction: normal;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
          
        }
        #spinner div{
          width: 15px;
          margin: 0;
          height: 15px;
          border-radius: inherit;
          border: 2.3px solid transparent;
          border-bottom: cyan solid 2px;
          border-top: cyan solid 2px;
          animation: gira 7s infinite  forwards;
          animation-direction: normal;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
        }
      
        @keyframes gira{
          0%{
            transform: rotate(0);
          }
          100%{
            transform: rotate(360deg);
          }
    
        }
```

```html
 

   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="spinnerLayer">
         <div>
           <span>99%</span>
           <div id="spinner">
              <div>
      
              </div>
           </div>
    
         </div>
         
       </div>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```